# NSTimer and UITabBar

Tags: iphone, nstimer, uitabbar

I have three tabbar items in one View. There is one NSTimer Schedule on Start Button Action in first tab item.When i press another tab item and come to the recent tab item(i.e tab item with NSTimer), it increases the seconds with 2. If i do the same for second time it increases the second with 3 and so on.I want seconds to be increased by 1.

This is the code i am using to schedule NSTimer

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

I have tried to solve it using [timer invalidate]; but it is not giving me a proper result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: I think he means that the timer becomes 2x and 3x faster.

Comment: He wants to increase it every time?

Answer (score 0):

in the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`
 method make timer invalidate by `[timer invalidate];`

and again start it by :

`timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`